# Angular distribution formula & Poynting's vector

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, x-rays, poynting-vector

I'm looking for a derivation of the [Angular distribution formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#Angular_distribution) of the "Bremsstrahlung" for radiated power as a function of angle (Bremsstrahlung is german for "deceleration radiation"):

$${\displaystyle {\frac {dP}{d\Omega }}={\frac {q^{2}}{16\pi ^{2}\varepsilon _{0}c}}{\frac {\left|{\hat {n}}\times \left(\left({\hat {n}}-{\vec {\beta }}\right)\times {\dot {\vec {\beta }}}\right)\right|^{2}}{\left(1-{\hat {n}}\cdot {\vec {\beta }}\right)^{5}}}}\tag{1}$$

where ${\displaystyle {\vec {\beta }}={\frac {\vec {v}}{c}}}$, and $ {\displaystyle {\hat {n}}} $ is a unit vector pointing from the particle towards the observer, and ${\displaystyle d\Omega } $ is an infinitesimal bit of solid angle.

The derivation in the reference in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, Sections 14.2–3 uses an argument I not understand:

On page 468, 14.2: Total Power Radiated...: Jackson defines in (14.18) the vector $\vec{E_a}$ and relates it with Poynting vector by $\vec{S}=  \frac{c}{4π}|\vec{E_a}|^2 \vec{n}$  (14.19). That's ok. Then he claims that $\frac{dP}{dΩ}=\frac{c}{4π}|R \vec{E_a}|^2 $ (14.20)

That's what I read. The last equation I not understand. It looks like that first equality in (14.20) falls from heaven. Could anybody explain it?

Comment: @G.Smith: I refered to page 468, 14.2: Total Power Radiated...: Jackson introduces vector $\vec{E_a}$ (14.18) and shows that for Poynting vector holds $\vec{S}= \frac{c}{4 \pi} \vert \vec{E_a} \vert^2 \vec{n}$ (14.19). Then he claims that $\frac {dP}{d\Omega }=  \frac{c}{4 \pi} \vert R \vec{E_a} \vert ^2$. (14.20) That's what I read. The last equation I not understand. That's the problem: it looks like that first equality in (14.20) "falls from heaven"

Comment: @G.Smith: With your first comment you are of course right. I was sloppy with the units. The main problem is the first equality in (14.20). I will modify my question...

Comment: The relationships you need are $S=dP/dA$ and $dA=R^2d\Omega$.

Comment: @G.Smith:Yes, the second relation is obvious. Why holds $S=dP/dA$? Here the units are compatible. Jackson introduces Poynting by definition as $\vec{S}= \frac{c}{4 \pi}  \vec{E} \times \vec{B}$. Unit's are now compatible: on both sides: $\frac{energy}{time \cdot surface}= \frac{power}{surface}$. But I nowhere find a proof why $S=dP/dA$, that is the "legitimation" calling the thing "energy flux".

Comment: Somewhere he must explain that the physical meaning of the Poynting vector is that it is the power *per unit area*. That is what “energy flux” means.

Comment: @G.Smith: Yes, on page 190 it is said "vector $\vec{S}$ represents *energy flow*". Why? The only observation is that as  you said it has dimension energy/area $\times$ time $=$ power per unit area. At first glance it's only a neccessary condition, some kind of "dimension check". Is it sufficient to conclude that $S$ is the density of the "whole" power on the surface of considered test volume?

Comment: Possibly I haven't clarified the point where I see a problem: I would like to draw a possibly silly analogy but for example if we consider a mechanical system then we have for example to differ between rotational energy $E_{rot}$ and translational $E_{trans}$ (which add up to kinetic energy), as well the potential energy although they all have same dimension. So $E_{rot}$ "knows" only a part of whole energy balance sheet. It provides no information about translational, potential etc. energies occuring in the system.

Comment: Now if we return to our $\vec{S}$ why can we assume that it represents the "total" energy flow through the surface of the considered test volume. Keeping the example with $E_{rot}$ from above in mind, one could ask if possibly $\vec{S}$ accounts only a part of the total energy flow, not the total. That is exactly what prevents me from argee that $\vec{S}$ is *the* energy flow part which accounts completely for the power on the surface. What do I miss at that point?