# Poynting vector & power flow

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, poynting-vector

I'm trying to understand why the Poynting vector coincides with the power flow. Firstly, the general "conservation theorem" of electrodynamics or the so called Poynting's theorem is:

$${\displaystyle \int _{V}{\vec {j}}\cdot {\vec {E}}\,\mathrm {d} V=-\int _{V}\left({\vec {\nabla }}\cdot {\vec {S}}+{\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}}\right)\,\mathrm {d} V}$$

with ${\displaystyle u:={\frac {1}{2}}({\vec {E}}\cdot {\vec {D}}+{\vec {B}}\cdot {\vec {H}})={\frac {1}{2}}(\varepsilon _{0}{\vec {E}}^{2}+\mu _{0}{\vec {H}}^{2})}$ and ${\displaystyle {\vec {S}}={\frac {1}{\mu _{0}}}\,({\vec {E}}\times {\vec {B}})}$ (the later is by definition the Poynting-vector).

It is easy to verify that the Poynting vector has the "right" dimension

$${\mathrm  {{\frac  {energy}{area \cdot {\mathrm  {time}}}}={\frac  {power}{area}}={\frac  {J}{m^{2}\cdot s}}={\frac  {W}{m^{2}}}={\frac  {N}{m\cdot s}}}}$$

What I don't understand is why does the Poynting vector correspond exactly to the power flow $ \frac {P} {A} $? Although the power flow would have the same dimension, the dimension check above does in general not imply that Poynting vector must correspond to the power flow.

A stupid example is, for example, kinetic energy does not correspond to potential energy just because its dimensions match.

I am looking for a comprehensible derivation that the Poynting vector corresponds exactly to the power flow $ \frac {P} {A} $. So something like we start with any physical system enclosed in a fixed volume $ V $, e.g. $ n $ atoms and we assume they don't leave the volume. They can emit electromagnetic radiation, which of course leaves the given volume at the speed of light. EM waves transport energy, so the system loses some energy over time due to the radiation, this energy loss per unit time corresponds to the power $ P $.

Since EM waves have propagation direction, we are looking for a vectorial function $ \vec{L} $ with the power flow that fulfills something like this: $ P = \int _{\partial V} \vec{L} \cdot dS $. This $ \vec{L} $ would be our power flow.

The question is why $\vec{L}=\frac {1}{\mu _{0}} (\vec {E} \times \vec {B})$? so why the Poynting vector?

P.S.: this quoestion is contentually related to discussion here: [Angular distribution formula & Poynting's vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540452/angular-distribution-formula-poyntings-vector)

Comment: Apply the divergence theorem to the first term on the right side of your first equation to convert it into a surface integral.

Comment: @G.Smith: Hi. That's clear, then the $S$-term becomes $\int _V \nabla \vec{S} dV= \int _{\partial V} \vec{S} \cdot d \vec{S}$. The problem is why $P = \int _{\partial V} \vec{S} \cdot d \vec{S}$? That is why the surface integral is exactly the power leaving the system by radiation.

Comment: The physical interpretation of your conservation theorem is: (rate of work done inside) equals (rate of energy flowing out) plus (rate of energy buildup inside).

Comment: By the way, you don’t want to use $\vec S$ to mean two different things, as in $\vec{S}\cdot d\vec{S}$.

Comment: @G.Smith: Ok, let call $\vec{S}$ Poynting, $d \vec{s}$ is the infinitisimal surface alement. So your argument is that's it's by exclusion.  We mathematically derived the expression 

$${\displaystyle -\int _{V}{\vec {j}}\cdot {\vec {E}}\,\mathrm {d} V=\int _{\partial V}\left({\vec {\nabla }}\cdot {\vec {S}}\right)\,\mathrm {d} \vec{s}+ \int _{V}\left ({\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}}\right)\,\mathrm {d} V}$$

Comment: and now we looking for the part which can possibly have something to do with flow at surface. Well, the first summand on the right is an integral over a surface, thus the integrand *must* represent  the power flow. Is this the logic behind it or is it a bit deeper?

Comment: Your equation in the comment is wrong.

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing “deeper”. It’s just a very straightforward interpretation of the equation.

Comment: Actually, there *is* an additional subtlety. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Adding_the_curl_of_a_vector_field

Comment: probably I confused somewhere a minus sign? I mean this one in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem#General in blue border frame

Comment: I’m talking about you wrongly converting a volume integral of the divergence into a surface integral of the divergence. When you do it right, as you did previously, there is no more divergence.

Comment: oh yes surry, there is no more nabla in the surface int, of course!

Comment: It is well known that the of choice of $E×B/\mu_0$ is arbitrary. As the Poynting theorem is global and not local, one could add any divergenceless field to it to get the same equality. But the standard choice is the most simple and it works well in all the typical cases.